# Regular Expression using VBA in Excel not matching as expected

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to parse a CSV file using a regular expression. I open the file and read it into a string. The regular expression string "([\s\S]*?)" matches on the website http://www.regexr.com/. The locals window states the FirstIndex item is at location 172. The very first characters in the file consist of "Plugin","Plugin Name". Not sure what I'm missing??

```
Dim Matches
Dim objectRegularExp As RegExp
Dim Match

If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
FileName = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
Open FileName For Input As #1
yourText = Input(LOF(1), #1)
Close #1
LengthOfFile = Len(yourText)
Set objectRegularExp = New RegExp
With objectRegularExp   ' "([\s\S]*?)"
     .Pattern = Chr(34) & Chr(40) & Chr(92) & Chr(115) & Chr(92) & Chr(83) & Chr(42) & Chr(63) & Chr(41) & Chr(34)
     .Global = True
     .MultiLine = True
End With

Set Matches = objectRegularExp.Execute(yourText)
```

Comment: do you realize that [\s\S]*? Is commented out?

Comment: Yes, the line below is contains the pattern, represented with the Chr() . in the immediate window the pattern is as seen on the comment line.

Comment: I have a gotten the regular expression to match the first occurrence on the line with:                                                                                               .Pattern = Chr(94) & Chr(34) & "([\s\S]*?)" & Chr(34)          this msdn article states you have to start matching at the beginning of the string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235254%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Your pattern is missing the '[...]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming from your pattern that you are trying to match strings enclosed by double-quote marks.

Your pattern is not what you think it is.  Your string of Chr's --

> "(\s\S*?)"

You are missing the `[  ]`

I would suggest

```
.Pattern = """([\s\S]*?)"""
```

Or, perhaps:

```
 .Pattern = Chr(34) & "([^" & Chr(34) & "]*)" & Chr(34)
```

OR

```
.Pattern = """([^""]*)"""
```

If you must use the string of Chr's, it would be:

```
.Pattern = Chr(34) & Chr(40) & Chr(91) & Chr(92) & Chr(115) & Chr(92) & Chr(83) & Chr(93) & Chr(42) & Chr(63) & Chr(41) & Chr(34)
```